Class of abstract linear spaces is no larger than the class of spaces with elements array of components.
While reading through Peter Lax's text on "Linear Algebra and its Applications" 2nd Edition, I came across the following quote right at the beginning of the first paragraph of Chapter 1.

This first chapter aims to introduce the notion of an abstract linear space to those
who think of vectors as arrays of components. I want to point out that the class of
abstract linear spaces is no larger than the class of spaces whose elements are arrays.
So what is gained by this abstraction?

Does anyone know what he means by this? I'm aware that finite-dimensional vector spaces are isomorphic to $\\R^n$ but I don't know if the same is true about infinite dimensional vector spaces

Hard to tell without reading the book. Maybe he forgot to say "finite-dimensional", maybe something else... Why don't you read chapter 1 to find out?

Every linear space has a basis (if we accept the Axiom of Choice). Given a basis ${b_j:j\in J}$ of $V$ for some index set $J$, we can express every element of $V$ as a finite linear combination of the $b_j$, hence as an array with one component for each element of $J$, all but finitely many components zero. So, each linear space corresponds to one whose elements are arrays.

Thanks. I wasn't aware that infinite dimensional vector spaces also have a basis. So I'm guessing here that the concept of arrays here may be extended to include an infinite number of components.(i.e sequences)
But doesn't that only makes sense for infinite dimensional vector spaces of countable dimension? What about infinite-dimensional spaces with uncountable dimension?

Sequences only make sense for countably infinite dimensions, but arrays indexed by an uncountable set $J$ make perfect sense in relation to uncountable dimensions. By the way, if you want to be sure I see a comment intended for me, you have to put @Gerry in it.

Perfect. Thanks @GerryMyerson for your responses. They really helped my understanding.
